# Add a "clicked effect" in my ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, visual-effects

I am creating a game for Android where the player has the choice to pick some dice from the board. Is there a way to add a *small visual effect* that can inform the player which dice has he choose? Each ImageView have a listener already.

The [Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyj4z.png) of the dice.

Comment: Yes.  Now if you want more of an answer than that, you need to give us some idea of what you want to show.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks for your reply. I am not searching for something complicated. A "brighter" lighting at the choosed dice will be just fine. If you have to suggest something cooler I am all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need the separate images for pressed and normal states.

For example

pressed_state image => pressed_dice_img.jpg
normal_state image =>  normal_dice_img.jpg

then you will have to make a selector file say dice_image_view_selector.xml in res/drawable folder like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     
     <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_dice_image" />    
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_dice_image" />
     <item android:drawable="drawable/normal_dice_image" />
</selector>
```

then apply to your each image view like this

```
android:background="dice_image_view_selector.xml"
```

Comment: @Ali Chha thiyae? :P upvote ta kares accept thiyo aa :D